# Avoiding Cloudinary image multiple transformation to resize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I'm using [cloudinary](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_gem) and [attachinary](https://github.com/assembler/attachinary) gems and the problem is that I have the original image kept with me in the column `picture` and it is repeatedly throughout the website done these transformations:

- resize to medium size;
- resize to smaller size.

using this method:

```
<%= cl_image_tag(p.path, :size => '398x235', :crop => :thumb) %>
```

It is good and smart unless that you have to pay for each transformation.

What I think is that we have to avoid it and create a copy of these pictures in another columns like `picture_medium` and `picture_small`. The point is:

1- How to do it in controller;

2- How the system will know what is the respective copy of a given picture.

Answer (score 1):

After talking with a Cloudinary attendant, they said that you won't pay twice for each image transformation. It means that one transformation is counted just one time even when you had 1.000x different users called it. So it is not something that we should work around on programming. Hope that this topic helps someone else with the same doubt.